# No master in alsamixer

Tags: linux, audio, arch-linux, alsa

I have problem with sound in Arch Linux; alsamixer worked well for one month. 
Then after a reboot, I can't find Master and other controls.  Here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot of alsamixer]

I installed Xubuntu and the sound doesn't work there, either.

Answer (score 0):

The audio hardware is not properly recognized by os. Try to run aplay -l from console and see what it shows. Copy a wav file (say test.wav) in a folder and open terminal in that folder. Run aplay --device=hw:0,0 test.wav
Try with every device listed by aplay -l. See if any play.  If you find something, there is a way to setup .asoundrc and pulseaudio to use that working device as default.

Comment: I removed pulseaudio for test before my question,when i installed pulseaudio again i see only 1 column with Master,but sound don't work

Comment: And sound in BIOS dont work too